# How can I add show 100 entries to dataTable.js

Tags: datatable

I want to add a new function like..."show 100 entries" to my dataTable.js.How can I make this function? I have pagination from 1 to 2038 and I want to add something like 25,50,100 entries to show in my page.

*Update:

I tried to use the code from here without html because I already have my table : https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/length_menu.html
but I've got an error : DataTables warning: Non-table node initialisation (DIV). For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/2

this was javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#example').DataTable( {
    "lengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, -1], [10, 25, 50, "All"]]
} );
```

} );

with library files link 
https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js
https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js

css: https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css

Comment: Can you please add code which you have tried here

Comment: check the new update pls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this:

```
$('#example').DataTable( {
    "lengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, 100, -1], [10, 25, 50, 100, "All"]]
} );
```

Comment: i've got this alert : DataTables warning: Non-table node initialisation (DIV). For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/2

Comment: You can load datatable on div element

Comment: how to do that? i just add id example to this div <div class="col-md-9" id="example">

Comment: You don't have any other table element to this page, right?

Comment: To load datatable you must have table element

Comment: this is all i have... This the only table I have on my page.So, I can't load datatable if I can't table element?

Comment: You have to use table element on the page to load datatable.